# Codeigniter and Bootstrap input form design

Tags: html, forms, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Input form shrinks after I submit the form. For example, if I go to my login page "/login" the form displays normally but after I click submit, the textfield size shrinks down.

**My Form on my view [view_login]**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/auth'); ?>

                    <div class="span3">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="user" name="username"class="span3" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="span3">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="passw" name="password" class="span3">
                    </div>


                    <div class="btn-group span4">
                        <input id="rst" type="reset" class="btn" name="reset" value="Reset">
                        <input id="smbt" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Login" value="Login">
                    </div>

                </form>
```

**Controller**

```
Class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('view_login');
    }

    public function auth() {
        /** Load required helpers and libraries*/
        //$this->load->library('session','database');


                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                //** Set rules */
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');


                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                    $this->load->view('view_login');
                }
                else{
                    redirect('admin_page');


                }



        echo 'Authentication takes place in here. :D';
    }
}
```

The image is here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEgBO.png

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the browser generated HTML that is displayed after submission?

Comment: Also does the page have: <!DOCTYPE HTML> still after submission, as a missing doctype usually causes this bootstrap issue.

Comment: what is the best site to upload the php file for you to preview the full version?

Comment: What happens if you redirect back to the index function when validation fails (instead of loading the view)? I.e. `redirect('login/index');`

Comment: If I redirect after validation fails on the "login/index", the form stays the same without problem. Is it a good step for logins?

Comment: js fiddle, but the html generated by the browser will be fine rather than your PHP.

Comment: @Bajongskie yes, I see nothing wrong with a redirect upon failed authentication. If you agree, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading a view when validation fails, try `redirect('login/index');`